# How to return list DTO contains a list of other DTO with query in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jpql

My DTO class:

```
     public class ArquivoProdutoPesquisarDTO extends BaseBean
     {

           private static final long serialVersionUID = -3046896345079547996L;

           private Long codigoProduto;      

           List<ArquivoProdutoVisualizarDTO> listaArquivoProdutoVisualizar;

           public ArquivoProdutoPesquisarDTO(Long codigoProduto, List<ArquivoProdutoVisualizarDTO> listaArquivoProdutoVisualizar)
           {
              super();
              this.codigoProduto = codigoProduto;
              this.listaArquivoProdutoVisualizar = listaArquivoProdutoVisualizar;
           }

      }
```

An example of what I wanted to do but that doesn't work:

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.sdf.app.dto.arquivoProduto.ArquivoProdutoPesquisarDTO(prd.codigo, lap) "
         + "  FROM Produto prd"
         + "  INNER JOIN prd.listaArquivoProduto lap"
         + " WHERE prd.codigo =:codigo")
   List<ArquivoProdutoPesquisarDTO> pesquisar(@Param("codigo") Long codigo);
```

Is it possible to do something that returns the list as DTO in the query?

Comment: This looks like you are trying to use a native JPA query when you could make your DTOs into `@Entity` with a `@OneToMany` relationship. Something like https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: I have @OneToMany relationship in my entity, but i want convert this directly in my DTO class